# Call ajax jquery depending on radio button id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question.

I have to Ajax-calls that recieves different data but takes in the same parameter. I want my radio buttons deciding wich one is going to fire:

```
 var value = $("input:radio[name=radio]").attr("id");
```

That's the code that gets the ID of the current radio button.

```
if (value === "something") {`Call Ajax here`}



else { call other ajax }
```

But it only calls the last ajax...even if I change radio button.

Comment: How your HTML looks like? And why did you chose `id` attribute as comparison value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
var value = $('input[name="radio"]:checked', '#myForm').val();


            $("input[name=radio]:radio").change(function() {
                $("#table").empty();
                $('#input').val('');
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to get `radio button` value and then compare as per your requirements but make sure about `===` or `==` comparison.Here `myForm` is your form `id`

```
 var active=$('input[type="radio"]:checked', '#myForm').val(); 
 if(active==1){
 //first ajax call
 }
 else if(active==2){
 //second ajax call
 }
 else{
  //last ajax call
 }
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYqx/913/)